# GAE and CloudSQL billing hours

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a small Java GAE hobby project using Google's CloudSQL MySQL and Hibernate. I have already used up my $300 promotional credit, and have been surprised just how expensive the CloudSQL is. Looking closer at the billing, it seems clear that I am being billed for almost continual running. A typical month invoice might specify:

***Cloud SQL DB standard Intel N1 1 VCPU running in Americas (with 30% promotional discount): 719 Hours***

I am certain that the db is actually be utilized a tiny fraction of that time. What are the factors in a GAE app that might cause the CloudSQL to be "running"? Is it primarily driven by the DB connection/pooling, as managed by Hibernate? Or is it dependent upon whether or not a GAE instance is running (which I believe is configurable?)?

Here are the connection pooling settings in my persistence.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL 2nd generation instances are [billed for every minute the instance is running](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing), regardless of if the instance is being used or not.

Cloud SQL 1st generation instances had a ["per use" billing option](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#per_use), where you were only billed for hours while the instance was being used. [Support for 1st gen instances is ending on Jan 30th, 2020](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#1st-gen-pricing).

Comment: Thanks for the response. When the CloudSQL 2nd generation documentation reference to an "instance", it means a CloudSQL instance, not a GAE instance, correct? So if my GAE app is not connected to CloudSQL, does that mean there is no CloudSQL instance running? Is it as simple as dropping the hibernate.c3p0.min_size to 0, such that there was no connection when GAE didn't need one? (after the timeout, of course)

Comment: Yes, the billing documentation he shared refers to Cloud SQL instances, not App Engine instances, Cloud SQL and App Engine are billed indecently of one another and regardless of their usage.

If you have a Cloud SQL instance turned on, you will be billed for each minute regardless the connections you have to it, if you want to reduce your invoice, I would recommend using cheaper Cloud SQL instances, or turning the instances off whenever you are not using them.